# Include interactive local R in presentation

Tags: html, r, knitr, slidify

In presentations we often want to demonstrate R interactively.  This requires exiting the presentation and demonstrating outside of the slides or running a limited (Things like `install_github` can't be used), unreliable (because Internet is unreliable in presentations) cloud based version of R (as seen in the code below).  How could a local version of R be run from within an HTML presentation?  In a similar fashion we can use `iframe` HTML tags to include videos etc. within a presentation.  This could make the presentation more seamless and flow better.

I know plotting tasks are likely much more difficult and would require a specific gui such as RStudio.  If that's possible it would be great but even if it were at a low level, that is include the OS command line with R booted up in the presentation.  Basically it would be like `iframe`-ing R from the command line or Rstudio within the .Rmd/.html document/presentation.

This would be able to be incorporated into the `slidify`, `knitr` as an .Rmd or within the [R Presentation](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/presentations/overview) (.Rpres) slide shows available in the latest version of RStudio.

So here's a version of this idea using a cloud based R that could be knit as a .Rmd file.  This is a starting point but being tied to a cloud is not ideal:

```
R in HTML
<iframe width='100%' height='300' src='http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/embed?id=e63tlTG8' allowfullscreen='allowfullscreen' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: Put R on a memory stick.

Comment: Embed http://www.r-fiddle.org/ as an iframe.

Comment: @Thomas I had thought of that and updated just before you commented, but the local version is ideal for presentations.

Comment: I think the right way to think about this is not as an R-specific solution, but rather how to get a shell into a presentation. These tex posts ([1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125317/embed-a-terminal-command-in-a-beamer-presentation), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22960/a-button-that-runs-an-external-program-from-a-beamer-pdf-presentation?lq=1)) look like they have some decent ideas, as does [this superuser post](http://superuser.com/questions/473700/how-to-embed-a-shell-and-browser-into-a-presentation).

Comment: This can be done with Slidify. See this [blog post](http://slidify.github.io/interactive/). It uses Shiny when run locally, and switches to OpenCPU when posted online (the OpenCPU binding is broken currently due to the update in OpenCPU).

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of Rstudio, you could simply install, on your presentation computer, the [RStudio **server** version](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/server/getting_started) which runs in a browser. You can then simply use an IFRAME as you want:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='300' src='http://localhost:8787' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Plots and figures work exactly as in RStudio regular version.

Answer (score 2):

One option is [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) app (or even multiple apps listening on different ports) running locally on your laptop. You will need a shiny app rendering your visual(s). Shiny can run from command line R.

Primitive shiny app takes 20-30 min to master (subjective opinion) and can incorporate arbitrary complex visualization produced with R.